# how do I test an interceptor which calls an observable with Angular 6+?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-http-interceptors, angular-unit-test

I have built an `HttpInterceptor` that closely follows the one in the Angular Documentation.

However, I needed to make an asynchronous call as part of my interceptor. I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-interceptor-observable) with a simplified version of the code (but identical in semantics).

The interceptor looks like:

```js
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private session: SessionService, private config: ConfigurationService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const apiRoot = this.config.apiUrl;
        if (apiRoot && req.url.startsWith(apiRoot)) {
            return this.addAuth(req).pipe(switchMap(x => next.handle(x)));
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }

    private addAuth(original: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpRequest<any>> {
        return from(this.session.getToken()).pipe(
            map(token => {
                const req = original.clone({
                    setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
                });
                return req;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

It's fairly simple:

- check if the URL we are calling requires our token ( `req.url.startsWith()` )
- if yes, then fetch our token and add it as a *header*
- if not, simply continue the pipeline

The `ConfigurationService` has a simple `string` property named `apiUrl`.
The `SessionService` has an almost equally simple method named `getToken()` which returns a `Promise<string>`.

The code works as expected:
[image: response with authorization header]

However, I am having a hard time testing this...

My actual test is very simple:

```js
it('should add authorization header for API call', () => {
    http.get('bar').subscribe();
    httpMock.expectOne(req => req.headers.has('Authorization'));
});
```

I have mocked the `getToken()` and `apiUrl` properly so that `apiUrl='bar'` and `getToken()` returns `Promise.resolve('foobar')`.
The problem seems to be *only* when going through the `addAuth()` path. If I test for the counter-case, it works:

```js
it('should NOT add authorization header for non-API call', () => {
    http.get('baz').subscribe();
    httpMock.expectOne(req => !req.headers.has('Authorization'));
});
```

Comment: I've never worked with Observable but the `subscribe` method is async no? It would explain why the header is not available.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant that's a good point. But I was just following the [documentation](https://v6.angular.io/guide/http#expecting-and-answering-requests).
I think it has to do with some unresolved promises...

Comment: So, by wrapping in a `fakeAsync()` and calling `tick()` after the `.subscribe()`, it seems to work. I am going to do some more digging to see if there is a more intuitive way...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as mentioned in one of my comments, the fix seems to be the use of `fakeAsync()` and `tick()` like this:

```js
beforeEach(()=>{
    spyOn(sessionService, 'getToken').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('foobar'));
});
it('should add authorization header for API call', fakeAsync(() => {
    http.get('bar').subscribe();
    tick();
    httpMock.expectOne(req => req.headers.has('Authorization'));
}));
```

While it makes sense, if anyone could clarify why I need to `tick()`... I thought that *resolving* the promise would be enough. I did try using `await http.get().toPromise();` (and using the `async` keyword - not the function), but that didn't work.